# Error uploading to Mac App Store: ITMS-90239

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, codesign, application-loader, productbuild

Let me start by saying I know there are myriad questions like this, but I believe I have checked all the causes in previous questions and still have a problem.

My application is using `Qt` so my submission process doesn't go through `Xcode`. In the past I have not had much trouble submitting my application.

Here is my `codesign` command:

```
codesign --deep -f -s '3rd Party Mac Developer Application: Me' -v --entitlements Entitlements.plist MyApp.app
```

This appears to work, and if I use `codesign` to verify I get:

```
MyApp.app: valid on disk
MyApp.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
```

Next up, I use `productbuild` to generate my `.pkg` file for submission via `Application Loader`.

```
productbuild --component MyApp.app /Applications --sign '3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: Me' MyApp.pkg
```

Note that I'm using `3rd Party Mac Developer` type certificates with both commands and I'm using the `Application` certificate for `codesign` and the `Installer` certificate for `productbuild`.

When I submit `MyApp.pkg` to `iTunesConnect` via `ApplicationLoader 3.1` I get:

> ERROR ITMS-90239: "Invalid Signature. Code object is not signed at
>   all. The binary at path [MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp] contains an
>   invalid signature. Make sure you have signed your application with a
>   distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development
>   certificate.

Evidently my code object is signed, so the problem must be that it thinks I'm using an `ad hoc` or `development` certificate, but as you can see from the commands I used, that isn't the case.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you get any solution to this ? I am getting the same error, please help.

Comment: I answered by own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution, at least in my case was not to include `Entitlements.plist` in the application bundle. It should still be specified when invoking `codesign`, but it need not be present in the bundle.

The error message made that abundantly clear!

Comment: Kindly provide complete details, How did you fixed that, Thanks.

Comment: There's nothing more to say. My bundle used to include the file `Entitlements.plist`, it no longer does.

Comment: My error code was -22421, and this answer also helps